# Envio de email funciona localmente mas não em servidor remoto

Tags: php, smtp, envio-de-email

Estou com um problema no envio de e-mail utilizando um servidor que eu criei em um *data center* contratado.

O envio de e-mail funciona local normalmente, embora o SMTP seja em uma conhecida empresa de hospedagem (vi que eles permitem 20 emails por dia de IP internacional). Já tentei usando outros serviços de e-mail e sempre funciona local.

```php
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = $host;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $user;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; 
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->From = $from_mail;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->addAddress($to);

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 
$mail->isHTML(true);                               

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $message;

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  exit;
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

O retorno sempre que eu tento enviar no servidor remoto é

> 2014-01-19 17:04:52 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:
>   Connection timed out (110) SMTP connect() failed. Message could not be
>   sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: @Victor e demais. Isso pode ser discutido aqui http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/513/o-que-fazer-com-perguntas-que-podem-parecer-ser-de-desenvolvimento-mas-se-revela e o fato de não termos Servefault não significa que devemos aceitar as peguntas dele. Se acha que devemos você pode propor em http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seu provedor está impedindo o SMTP em seu servidor / hospedagem, abra um ticket de suporte e pergunte sobre a liberação.

É uma prática comum entre provedores de hospedagem / servidores manter o tráfego SMTP bloqueado para evitar que os clientes enviem SPAM.

Alguns não liberam tal acesso em planos mais básicos, mesmo sob solicitação.

Comment: Imaginei que fosse isso, mas acho que é alguma configuração que eu tenho que liberar, de qualquer forma eles não oferecem suporte nesse sentido, o servidor não é gerenciado.

Comment: Não, não é você que libera ou não tal configuração, é quem administra sua hospedagem / servidor.

Comment: eu tenho acesso root.

Comment: @DanielLemes Mesmo com acesso root, o bloqueio pode estar no Firewall do servidor [físico]. Ou talvez ele precise criar um *endpoint* para a porta X (tive esse problema no passado com um servidor Azure). Ou seja, mesmo o [a instância do] servidor não sendo gerenciado, o problema pode estar **externo** a ele...

Comment: @DanielLemes talvez você tenha mais sorte instalando e configurando um servidor de email no servidor que você controla.